# SpringXD 1.1.0- JDBC source connection issues with SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc, spring-batch, spring-xd

We have installed `spring-xd` version **1.1.0** and trying to stream data from sql server via JDBC driver using `xd-singlenode`. After deploying the stream, it is giving us error that:

```
port 1433/databasename is not valid
```

For testing purpose we also fetched data from postgressql and it is connecting to the database.

We have created stream as:

```
stream create connectiontest --definition "jdbc --url=jdbc:sqlserver://databaseIP:1433/Databasename 
                                            --driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --username=sample 
                                            --password=***** --query= 'SELECT * FROM schema.tablename' |log" --deploy
```

Error is:

```
1.1.0.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-3 handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 1433/Databasename is not valid.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:245)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:457)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 1433/Databasename is not valid.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:691)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:186)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204)
        ... 21 more
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In JDBC URL, did you try something like `jdbc:sqlserver://databaseIP:1433;Databasename=name_of_database`?

Comment: Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: XD100E:(pos 65): Found unexpected data after stream definition: ';'
jdbc --connectionProperties=jdbc:sqlserver://databaseIP:1433;database=Database_name --driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --username=sample --password=*** --query='SELECT * FROM schema.tablename' |file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the GitHub issue here - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/issues/1521

If you need to add a database name as a property in the JDBC URL you need to enclose the URL in single quotes like:

```
--url='jdbc:sqlserver://databaseIP:1433;database=Database_name'
```